# Безопасность mt_rand

Tags: криптография

Интересует безопасность функции:

```
mt_rand()
```

Если использовать:

```
md5(mt_rand())
```

то это не безопасно. А будет ли безопасным если использовать:

```
md5(mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand())
```

Или можно взломать данную конструкцию?

Comment: Зависит от реализации mt_rand() и около него. Если инициализация mt_rand происходит однократно и 32-битным значением - да, такое можно "взломать".

Comment: Клаудфляра держит помещение с лава-лампами, снимая рандом с них. Такой вариант сломать несколько сложнее.

Comment: @bukkojot или говоря, что снимая...

Comment: Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-rand.php): *Предостережение. Данная функция не генерирует криптографически безопасные значения и не должна использоваться в криптографических целях. Если вам требуется криптографически безопасное значение, подумайте об использовании функций `random_int()`, `random_bytes()`, или `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` вместо данной.* Иными словами, не стоит пытаться использовать `mt_rand()` там, где от неё требуется невозможное — надёжная непредсказуемость.

Comment: `md5(mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand())` — ни в коем случае! Так как `mt_rand()` является генератором **псевдо**случайных чисел, то вы просто уменьшаете весь диапазон генерируемых значений в четыре раза, во столько же раз приближая исчерпание генерируемого  диапазона и уход на новый круг, в точности повторяющий предыдущий.

Comment: Каким образом можно взломать данную конструкцию? Вить он генерируется каждый раз с новым сидом, а при взломе нужны все 4 верно подобранные значения mt_rand(), можно же вить вместо 4 добавить ещё 4, или сколько не добавляй, дела не меняет? Я то читал, это не безопасно использовать данную функцию, но если к примеру будет "md5(mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand())"? Тоже можно взломать такое, если человек знает только md5 хеш? Объясните, пожалуйста, по подробнее.

Comment: Так же получается очень много комбинаций для перебора, разве что если знать разницу между сидами для каждого значения, но это не реально мне кажется, потому что для кажого хеша будет разная разница между сидами.

Comment: Не пойму, каким образом можно взломать такую конструкцию "md5(mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_ra‌​nd().mt_rand().mt_ra‌​nd().mt_rand().mt_ra‌​nd().mt_rand().mt_ra‌​nd())"?

Comment: Arhad, объясните пожалуйста